# How use Kotlin class in Java class in spring boot 2?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, kotlin

I create a spring boot project from [spring boot starter](https://start.spring.io) with bellow configs:

- **Language:** *Kotlin*
- **Spring Boot:** *2.2.0 M3*
- **Packaging:** *war*
- **Java:** *12*

Now I add 2 simple classes as follows:

A Kotlin class:

```
class KotlinModel(
   var name: String = "",
   //var model: JavaModel
)
```

A Java class:

```
class JavaModel {
   private String name = "";
   //private KotlinModel model;
}
```

When I uncomment `//var model: JavaModel`, The project compile successfully, But when I uncomment `//private KotlinModel model;` occure error:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: class KotlinModel
location: class fava.model.JavaModel
```

`pom.xml` is as follow:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.M3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.31</kotlin.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <compilerPlugins>
                    <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    <plugin>spring</plugin>
                </compilerPlugins>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                </args>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                    <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Where is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: don't write Kotlin AND Java into *the same* file?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No, they are in separate file.

Comment: Paste the build.gradle file

Comment: @SaeedEntezari Question updated.

Comment: Might help: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#calling-kotlin-from-java

Comment: Please give the complete file contents with their locations (packages matter).